# Constantly get java.io.NotSerializableException

Tags: java, serialization

I have a class called Parameters, which implements Serializable. But when I use writeObject(p), I got the error message. I checked the status of p. It says it is already Serialized.

```
package Server.Interface;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Parameters implements Serializable{
    private String command;
    private String location;
    private ArrayList<Integer> numbers;
    public Parameters(String command, String location,ArrayList<Integer> numbers) {
        this.command = command;
        this.location = location;
        this.numbers = numbers;
}

    public String getCommend() {
        return command;
    }

    public void setCommend(String c) {
        this.command = c;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setNumbers(ArrayList<Integer> numbers) {
        this.numbers = numbers;
    }
}
```

The code of client:

```
public void sendMessage(Parameters p) {
    try {
        if(p instanceof Serializable){
            System.out.println("can be serialized");
        }
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        oos.writeObject(p);
        InputStream is=socket.getInputStream();
        int attempts = 0;
        while(is.available() == 0 && attempts < 1000)
        {
             System.out.println(attempts);
             attempts++;
             try {
                 Thread.sleep(10);
             }
             catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
             }
        }
        System.out.println("============================");
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        System.out.println("============================");
        String info=null;
        while((info=br.readLine())!=null&&info.length()>0){
            System.out.println(info);
            break;
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IOError");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is the message:

```
can be serialized
IOError
java.io.NotSerializableException: Client.TCPClient
```

It clearly says that the object is serialized. But writeObject(p) fails. I also tried set the arraylist of p to be null, and it passed. But ArrayList is serializable in default right? It should not affect the serialization.

Comment: Parameters is probably an inner class of Client.TCPClient. Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem. And don't hide the stack trace.

Comment: If JB Nizet is correct, just add `static` to your class. You might also want to add `final` to ensure no one subclasses it.